# Web Based Streaming Media Server

Tags: php, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to build a Media Server that will be used only on my own personal network.  No outside access will be available, except for those devices that are connected via LAN or WiFi.  I have ripped my entire DVD collection some SD, and some HD as to be able to play it via PS3, DVD Players, etc, without having to dig the disc out every time someone wants to watch something.  Because I want to limit access to certain parts of the media, VLC, TVersity, Plex, etc don't work, and I want to custom tailor it with my own design without having to go to any outside source for processing and want it to be web based so it can be viewable in Safari or Chrome.  All files are in .mp4 format, so transcoding is not necessary, or at least I don't think it is.

I have a working page that works on the machine that the XAMPP server is running on.  The info is provided via a MySQL database and using PHP and HTML5 to play the video.  I will be building a dedicated Linux server very soon, just trying to get it working. Files under 2GB work just fine on the same machine as XAMPP is installed (but NOT on devices that are connected via wifi or wire), but anything over 2GB just continuously say loading on all devices.  Trying to view on iPad Air, iPhone6 but doesn't work.

The Streaming Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Description of VideoStream
 *
 * @author Rana
 * @link http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial
 */
class VideoStream
{
    private $path = "";
    private $stream = "";
    private $buffer = 102400;
    private $start  = -1;
    private $end    = -1;
    private $size   = 0;

    function __construct($filePath) 
    {
        $this->path = $filePath;
    }

    /**
     * Open stream
     */
    private function open()
    {
        if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb'))) {
            die('Could not open stream for reading');
        }

    }

    /**
     * Set proper header to serve the video content
     */
    private function setHeader()
    {
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
        $this->start = 0;
        $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
        $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
        header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

            $c_start = $this->start;
            $c_end = $this->end;

            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];

                $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            $this->start = $c_start;
            $this->end = $c_end;
            $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
            fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header("Content-Length: ".$length);
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
        }
        else
        {
            header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
        }  

    }

    /**
     * close curretly opened stream
     */
    private function end()
    {
        fclose($this->stream);
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * perform the streaming of calculated range
     */
    private function stream()
    {
        $i = $this->start;
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
            if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
                $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
            }
            $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
            echo $data;
            flush();
            $i += $bytesToRead;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start streaming video content
     */
    function start()
    {
        $this->open();
        $this->setHeader();
        $this->stream();
        $this->end();
    }
}
?>
```

The HTML Code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls><?php 
$stream = new VideoStream($row_rsTitles['Category'].'/'.$row_rsTitles['Title'].'/'.$row_rsTitles['Filename']);
$stream->start();
?></video>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Many of hours, and trying a hundred different options with no success.

Comment: Maybe that happens because your php version is under 5.6 , all other versions can not work with files over 2 GB

Comment: you can't just put php code in a middle of video tag and expect it to work, read how html5 video api works

Comment: So are you saying that the reason it doesn't work is that it has php code in the video tag?  Why would some work, and others not.

The code that I posted with the question was working code, with php code in the video tags.  I just added the dynamic link to the video file.

Sorry if I sound stupid, but this is the first time I have done html5 video stuff.

Comment: You should have three separate files containing the following:
VideoStream.php:
`...the whole VideoStream class...`

videoLink.php:
`...$stream = new VideoStream($pathToVideo);
$stream->start();...`

index.html
`...<video src="/videoLink.php"></video>...`

Comment: I have setup the pages as you indicated, but how do I pass the variable to the videoLink.php page without putting PHP in the <video> tag (ie. ?ID=3 to tell the database what movie it is?)?  Sorry if that sounds like a stupid question.

Comment: Do not apologize, it's normal not to know everything :) No, you can use php on on your page, i said you can not put video itself using php, but if you want to put a link using php, nodody forbids you

Comment: Even if I put a hard-coded link, videos over 2GB still don't play.  Anything under that size work just fine.

Comment: I've done a little research, and it turns up that this issue has something to do with 32 bit operating systems, so with 64 bit it should work fine

Comment: I guess I am dead in the water on this issue for now, as I am running a 64-bit version of Windows 7, but there is no XAMPP server that is 64-bit for Windows, just Linux.

Comment: http://windows.php.net/download

Comment: Downloaded the (I think the appropriate) .zip file.  Looked in several places on how to copy and configure the setup, but when I do what is suggested, Apache won't restart.  Will continue to tinker with it to see if I can get it to work.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You only need to find where is your php application folder and replace its content with content of the zip file